# Installing WordPress on an AWS instance (not through AWS Marketplace)

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I need help installing WordPress on my new Amazon EC2 instance.

I created it and I have SSH and SFTP working through FileZilla (using PuTTY because I'm on Windows 10). I also have my Google domain name pointing to the IPv4 address as well.

How do I install WordPress on my site now? I don't want to install it initially when setting up the instance through the AWS marketplace with bitnami or whatever.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming at all and is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow these steps to install the WordPress in AWS:

1. Log in to AWS using SSH.
2. Go to Root Folder (`/var/www/html/`).
3. Check whether **wp cli** is installed or not. If not, please install. [The installation guide is here](https://wp-cli.org/).
4. Create a folder in the name of the project.
5. Get into the folder (**cd folder name**).
6. Use command **wp core download** (it will install the latest version).
7. Use command **wp core config --dbname=`<dbname>` --dbuser=`<dbuser>` --dbpass=`<dbpassword>` --dbhost=localhost** (it will create wp-config.php file)
8. Use command **wp db create** (create database in named as previous command)
9. Use command **wp core install --url=http://`<yoursiteurl>` --title=`<Project Name>`--admin_user=`<adminuser>` --admin_password=`<adminpassword>` --admin_email="`<youremailid>`"**

It will install WordPress in AWS. We followed the same with successful installation many times. Please find the automated script at GitHub (https://github.com/trisghosh/wordpress-automated-script). Please use the automated one after you complete at least one manual installation.